# Can not connect jtds 1.3.1 with sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server, jasperserver, jtds

I install jasperserver 5.0.0 and ireport 5.0.0 too. And in iReport I can create report with jtds 1.3.1 with sql server 2000. But in jasperserver I put jtds in ../tomcat/lib and in ../webapp/jasperserver/web-inf/lib. And when I create datasource in jasperserver and click test connection it display "Internal server error occurred. Please contact your system administrator." Please tell me "what I do something wrong?" 
the driver i put : net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
the URL i put : jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server-ip/database-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve my problem. I use JTDS 1.2.7 to connect SQL server 2000 and it's worked. But In input control you must to modify the query that uses parameter

Thank you very much